# Enable DDNS with in series connected router

Tags: router, home-networking, dd-wrt, openwrt, ddns

After a bandwidth upgrade, my ISP required me to use a new modem device, which is a **modem/router hybrid** — contrary to my old device, which was **modem only**.

The old modem-only device provided the connected ([dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/)-enabled) router with the WAN IP address, which then could be used with the router's intern [Dynamic DNS (DDNS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service.

With the new hybrid device (10.1.9.1) this approach isn't working anymore, since the connected router now has a LAN IP address (10.1.9.2), which it tries to use with the DDNS service.

[image: WAN Connection Type displaying the WAN IP Address of 10.1.9.2]

---

The router's Dynamic DNS outputs following message to log, as you can see the local IP address `10.9.1.2` is used.

```
   Wed Sep 2 22:03:53 2015: INADYN: Started 'INADYN Advanced version 1.96-ADV' - dynamic DNS updater. 
   Wed Sep 2 22:03:53 2015: I:INADYN: IP address for alias 'sub.domain.com' needs update to '10.1.9.2'
```

<sup>note: `sub.domain.com` is not the real domain</sup>

---

**Question**

Are there ways to get DDNS working on a router that is connected to the internet, but has not been assigned a WAN IP?

---

**Additional Information**

- The hybrid device, which is an **Ubee EVW3226**, does not support DDNS
- It has an OEM firmware with a simpler interface and reduced options
- It can't be replaced (without renting an uber-expensive alternative)
- Related question I asked some month ago: [How to link two routers LAN to WAN](https://superuser.com/questions/870361/how-to-link-two-routers-lan-to-wan)

Comment: The problem you have is that your DDNS client on your router can't differentiate the immediate IP of the WAN socket and the real IP as seen by the Internet - which is usually achieved using a small script that is hosted on the Internet (by one of the DDNS services) and allows your router to find out your real public IP so it can feed this back to the DDNS service and keep the domain up-to-date. An alternative solution may be to install your DDNS service's client on a PC in your LAN - this will do the DDNS update for you.

Comment: Updated question with model info.

Comment: @BigChris I tried the alternative on my NAS and it works (wget script as a cron job), the same should work on the dd-wrt router, too. The router's DDNS client, INADYN, seems to be insufficient for such a scenario. Disadvantage is, using scripts, the resulting logs are no longer displayed in the DDNS tab on the web interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into bridging your particular modem/router.  Most of the combination router/ modems I have worked with allow you to bridge.  Post the model of the modem/router and I will update this answer with a tutorial on how to do if it is possible in your scenario.

Comment: Model is a **Ubee EVW3226**, I found out that one can access the hidden option for switch mode at http://10.1.9.1/cgi-bin/setup.cgi?gonext=RgSystemSwitchMode, but apparently the changes get revoked within an short interval. I didn't try it myself yet, since I wanted to safe potentially unecessary configuration work,

Comment: Don't let the buggers control you like that.  Buy a modem with 8 downstream like the ubee(motorola sb6121 would work), call in the MAC address to your ISP, problem solved

Comment: Already thought about buying one, but the tech support at unity media told  me that I can't, since the customers are provided with customized versions of the modem (different port, because internet is provided via cable)

Comment: I took a look online, and the major cable modems all have the cable port I need. Some also support MAC spoofing, so I can avoid dragging my ISP into this.

Comment: Could you skip the 2nd router being a dhcp server (plug the modem into a switch port on the 2nd router instead of the wan port) and see if that works?

Comment: I tried to configure that, but somehow I couldn't get it to work. But in the end, I'll have to change the setup. Because I understand that, in order to fully support multiple subnets (e.g. I can't reach the second subnet from outside right now), I need to be able to change the routing tables, which I can't on the modem/router.

Comment: I guess we are stuck on spoofing your MAC address on a new cable modem then :P  I work with ISPs on a constant basis, and find new reasons every day to hate them more, lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27734/discussion-between-mike-and-steven).

Comment: Np. Sry I have to ask again. Motorola sb6121 is only the chipset. Not a device itself?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/ARRIS-SURFboard-SB6141-DOCSIS-Cable/dp/B00AJHDZSI

Sorry, the Motorola SB6141 is what I meant, NOT the SB6121(it is only 4 downstream)

Comment: Does it support mac spoofing? I coudn't find anything on the net, yet.

Comment: ack, sorry - forgot about the mac spoofing.  As far as I can tell, it does not support mac cloning.  HOWEVER, most routers do, so I would just look for a modem/router combination that has ddns as well(most do as well)